# horizontal list inside vertical list not smoothly on jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I'm trying to implement a screen that use a vertical scroll to show all the contents and some sections of this screen has a horizontal scroll with cards like this:

[image]

The screen composable:

```
LazyColumn{
    item { header }
    item { texts }
    item {
       LazyRow{
         items(firstCardList){}
       }
       LazyRow{
         items(secondCardList){}
       }
    }
}
```

The scrolls are working fine but not smoothly, I don't know how to explain but when I move the list with my finger, the scroll stop when I remove my finger of the screen, it's not smoothly and continuous the scroll like the vertical, looks like the scroll animation is stuck.

I know that in xml I can use **nestedScrollingEnabled = false** and this problem is solved, but I don't know how to do this in compose.